# can't copy 'ANIFEST.in': doesn't exist or not a regular file

Tags: pip, setuptools, distutils

***NOTE:*** As of Sep. 4th, 2015, I can no longer reproduce this problem, using current versions of python and setuptools/distutils, in either python 2 or 3.

---

*NOTE*: I've answered this question myself and will be accepting the answer as soon as the system lets me, but this would appear to be the only instance of an English-language reference to the problem on the internet (according to google), so I thought I'd post both in hopes this can be useful.

---

I ran into a problem that I found impossible to debug when installing a python package of my own.  It's a very simple package, with a flat structure (no subdirectories), and a few data files I need copied over at installation.  With a few deletions for brevity, I have this:

```
spherical_functions
├── MANIFEST.in
├── __init__.py
├── spherical_functions.py
├── ladder_operator_coefficients.npy
└── setup.py
```

When installing from my source directory, I have no problems.  But when I either switched to `setuptools` or installed with `pip` (which is needed for distribution), I get the error

```
can't copy 'ANIFEST.in': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Note the missing `M` at the beginning of that file name.  I hacked into `distutils` a bit to verify that it was actually trying to copy `ANIFEST.in`, rather than just misreporting the name.  Unfortunately, the trail ends there, because the rest of the setuptools code is hidden in some egg I don't understand.

A similar problem arises without a `MANIFEST.in` file, using just the `package_data` option to the `setup` function, where it misses the first letter of the data file, as in

```
error: can't copy 'adder_operator_coefficients.npy': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

Comment: Even if you answer indicates that you found a solution which works for you, I'd like to ask you to file a bug against `setuptools`/`distutils` regarding the bad/errornous feedback in the error message (simply doesn't make sense and is confusing in multiple aspects) as you already took a look into the code. I could do the same if you don't want to, but I'd have to do the work which you already did. What do you think?

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this issue, with either python 2 or 3 (installed as environments in anaconda).  I first tried with a MWE, based on my original question; then I rolled back my repo to its state just before I asked this question the first time.  None of those combinations gave me a problem, so I guess it was resolved already.  If you can reproduce the error, of course, you should file a bug report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a hint from [this thread](http://lists.python.it/pipermail/python/2014-February/018063.html), I realized that I was making the mistake; I didn't really understand all the options to the `setup` function in `setup.py`.  I had

```
package_dir={'spherical_functions': ''},
```

when I should have had

```
package_dir={'spherical_functions': '.'},
```

(Note the extra dot.)  After including this, it seems to work just fine.

I might suggest that the resulting behavior is wrong in any case, suggesting a bug in setuptools and/or distutils.  Or at least there could be a check to ensure that the user didn't do something stupid like I did...

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can just use the `py_modules` keyword to `setup()`, which should simply be a list of module (file) names to install, if you wish. This is the simplest kind of python distribution.

```
setup(...
      py_modules=['spherical_functions'],
      ...)
```

In this manner, after installing your distribution, one could simply run `from spherical_functions import <a_member_inside_that_file>`.

Comment: That doesn't work at all for my files; if I include such a line, I just get `file spherical_functions.py (for module spherical_functions) not found`, with no other change to the build process.  If I include only that line, I get `no Python modules to install`.  I may have left out some salient detail, but basically I can't see any way of making installation work without both `packages=['spherical_functions']` and `package_dir={'spherical_functions': '.'}`.